# Ways to avoid user from accessing page with querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a page that I want it to be accessed when the user finishes saving the form. I have a `Response.Redirect("MyPage.aspx?queryStringParam=123")` (the value chages, based on field selection) .

On the page I have a check to see if the value is being passed and everything is working:

```
if (Request.QueryString["queryStringParam"] != null)
{
    int queryStringParam;
    if(int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["queryStringParam"], out id))
    {
        hfQueryStringParam.Value = queryStringParam.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx"));
    }
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx"));
}
```

If the user tryes to type the page, it checks for the queryString and if it's not being passed, it will redirect him to the default page, but hte problem is, if he types the queryStringParam into the url, the page will load. I don't want that to happen.

Is there any way to block the user from accessing the page by typing the url and only access it with `Response.Redirect`?

Comment: No, that's not possible. This is an XY problem. Explain what you use this parameter for and how you generate it.

Comment: That parameter is the ID returned from the database after it's been saved. Then it redirects to another page to be able to add attatchments to it. But I want it to be accessed only when it's created. It's not suposed to be accessed again

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "XY Problem"?

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the page where you are saving the form,store something in the session just before the redirection to MyPage.aspx. In the MyPage.aspx first check for the session value. If it does not have a value which you set from the previous page, redirect the user to the default page.

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks. Can't accept answer yet. Will in 5 min

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to prevent a page from accessed from typing the url. Only accept if request comes from the server itself

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi But the request does *not* come from the server. The server sends a response to the user's browser saying "go to X" and the user's browser then requests "X" from the server.

Comment: Could you write a simple cookie and check for its existence too?

Comment: Session is stored in the server. So checking for a session variable means you are verifying it.

Comment: @FelipeDeguchi Did this answer help you resolve the problem? If so please mark it as answer!